# Connect to a database on a lamp server with php

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, lamp

I have a database on a lamp server and want to connect to this database with a windows 7 pc from my home and use queries.

With putty I can connect with the server with ssh. First connect with ssh, then connect to the  mysql database.

In php do I need to use ssh2 libraries like phpseclib and connect trough ssh2 and use the interactive shell or is there a way to connect with the database directly. Thus skipping the shell?

Thanks.

Comment: ssh tunneling is the answer: http://statistics.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/mysqlt.html

Comment: I got a response, but now "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
<?php
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root_user","root_password")
         or die("problems connecting to DB.");

  mysql_select_db("my_database",$connection) 
         or  die("Problems selecting DB.");

  $records = mysql_query("select id, name, school from students",$connection) 
         or die("Problems on querying " . mysql_error() );

  while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($records)) {
    echo "id: " . $record['id'] . "<br>";
    echo "name: " . $record['nombre'] . "<br>";
    echo "school: " . $record['school'] . "<br>";
  }
  mysq_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this gives no response. Don't I need to connect to the server first and then with the sql database?

| Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: Did you solve it? If it says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", it means the password is wrong. Look at the documentation for the password.